# Branch predictor based on probability

Tags: assembly, branch, probability, branch-prediction

Given some assembly code ,it is known that 90% of branches should be taken.

I have no knowledge regarding branch conditions.And decision about take or not take for each branch should be done only based on probability.

The branch`s offset can be positive or negative.

What is correct algorithm to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an algorithm, but I do not know if it is the right for your case

[Here it is](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f00/docs/mpr-branchpredict.pdf)

Hope you find it useful!